# sub array and push data

Tags: javascript, arrays

hello I am trying to create a dynamic array, but I am having problems, I have an `onclick` event to create invoice so when clicked is launched and I have it

```
var $boletos=new Array();
function onclick(value){
     if($invoice.length==0){
       $invoice.push({"items":{}}); 
       $invoice[0].items[0]={"ID":this.person.ID,"other":value};
    }else{
      //here i do a "for" to create new invoice index, or new item 
         ....
       }
}
```

the result I want is something like

```
Invoice{

      0:{ items{             
              0:{ ID:"123",other:"xxx"}
              1:{ ID:"234",other:"xxx"}
              2:{ ID:"233",other:"xxx"}
             }
         }
      1:{ items{             
              0:{ ID:"1323",other:"yyy"}
              1:{ ID:"1323",other:"xyyxx"}
              2:{ ID:"1213",other:"yyyy"}
             }
         }
      2:{ items{             
              0:{ ID:"12323",other:"zz"}
              1:{ ID:"1223",other:"zz"}
              2:{ ID:"1123",other:"zz"}
             }
         }
}
```

but i can do only an object, i can't call a push event, and is because is an object, and not an array, so maybe I need to do something like 
`$invoice[0].items[0].push({"ID":this.person.ID,"other":value});` please help me

Comment: Do you want to create an array of Invoices or items in the invoice? It looks like you are trying to do 2 different things. What is the source being used for the items & objects?

Comment: i want do, a sub array for each invoice, and subarray for item in invoice , like `$invoice[0].items[0].ID`, `$invoice[0].items[1].ID` ..etc

Comment: beouce i have several invoice, each invoice have several items, and items have data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't entirely understand the logic you're using here, but basically you should be using `push()` to add new items to the array, and not numeric indices. The `items` property should also be an array, not an object:

```
var $boletos = [];

function onclick(value){
    if($boletos.length === 0 || shouldStartANewInvoice) {
        $boletos.push({ items: [] }); 
    }

    $boletos[$boletos.length - 1].items.push({
        ID: this.person.ID,
        other:value
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks, I was confused...and   ` $invoice.push({"items":{}});` wrong becouse i declare a object `{}` and no array `[]`, ty again

Answer (score 0):

Just to add context and example to @JLRishe's answer.

There are really 2 ways you could do this depending on your use case for the Invoice. If I were submitting it server side in C#, for example, I would structure it more like an object (#2). Otherwise, the array approach works just fine (#1).

1. As he suggested where Items is an array: http://jsfiddle.net/nv76sd9s/1/
2. An alternative is to have Items be an object with the ID as the key and the value as the value: http://jsfiddle.net/nv76sd9s/3/

The difference here is the structure of the final object and how you plan to use it. In my #2 link, the object is more structured. It also affects how you iterate through them. Example:

```
    var items = Invoice.Items;
    for (k in items) {
        var item = items[k];
        for (k in item) {
            console.log(k +': '+item[k]);
        }
    }
```